# Q 2.0.0 installed with Bower causes Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: bower, q

I am using Q in a project, and I am using bower to manage my JS dependencies.  I am including Q 2.0.0 with bower in bower.json

```
"dependencies" : {
    "q": "~2.0.0"
}
```

In my index.html, I include Q with a script tag

```
<script src="bower_components/q/q.js"></script>
```

When I load the page, I see in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined q.js:43

Line 43 of q.js:

```
require("collections/shim");
```

What am I missing here?  Should I be using Browserify or require.js to get this to work?  I expected the library to be accessible by simply using a  tag.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bower is not very smart about selecting versions. As it happens, there is a 2.0 release train that is not compatible with Bower at all. You will want to install q#1.0.1 specifically.

Comment: Thanks, would it just be better to grab q from github and include it that way, so that I can use 2.0?

Comment: I don’t recommend using the v2 release train at this time, especially on Bower. It has not solidified enough for general use.

Comment: I hit the same issue. At first I thought q had a hard dependency on requriejs (which was puzzling) and went ahead requirifying my project only to discover this. #latenightcoding

Comment: If you've come from the future: the current version at the time of this comment is 1.5.0. You can install via bower using `bower install --save q#1.5.0`